# How to interchange arguments in functions?

Tags: r

I'm new to programming and was kind of stuck on this question. I don't really know how to interchange str1 and str2. Thank you so much

Define a function `is_twice_as_long` that takes in two character strings, and  # returns whether or not (e.g., a boolean) the length of one argument is greater # than or equal to twice the length of the other.

```
is_twice_as_long <- function(str1, str2) {
  test <- nchar(str1)
  test1 <- nchar(str2)
  return(test >= test1*2 | test1 >= test*2)
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a different method? What does this function not do that you want it to do?

Comment: Yea I guess I wanted to make the function a bit simpler if I could! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only suggestion might be to use `max` and `min` to avoid the double comparison. This also allows you to accept multiple strings if so desired. Note that this is not actually faster or obviously (imho) clearer, but it is a little more flexible because of the multiple strings option.

```r
is_twice_as_long <- function(...) {
  lengths <- nchar(c(...))
  return(max(lengths) >= 2 * min(lengths))
}

is_twice_as_long("a", "Ab")
#> [1] TRUE
is_twice_as_long("ac", "Ab", "abc")
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ohhh. That makes things a lot more simpler and flexible! Thank you